# Angular: <link rel="preload"> in index.html for generated web worker

Tags: angular, preload

I have a Angular app containing a **web worker** implementation (generated via `ng generate webWorker`).

I want to mark the given **web-worker for preloading**, like this:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   ...
    <link rel="prefetch" href="worker.js" />
   ...
  </head>
 ....
</html>
```

The problem is that the name of the `worker.js` file is generated via Angular CLI, e.g. `0.7841408a8c7c04e45900.worker.js` (bundled from `worker.ts`)

Is there a way to put a placeholder of the filename into the index.html, which is replaced by the actual filename at build time?

Comment: can't you do that after the build step? you can a script that looks for the file and then inject it in the html file, or just leave the `<link rel="prefetch" href="worker.js" />` there and the script would replace the filename with the correct one.

Comment: Which version of CLI are you using? When ever I run `ng generate web-worker` it does ask me to specify the file name.
`

Answer (score 3):

In angular.json file, mention the worker file path in the scripts 
section.

```
build: {
    ...,
    options: {
        "scripts": ['./worker.js']
    }
}
```

By default, Angular will inject the files mentioned in the scripts 
array directly into the html. If you do not want the angular to inject
you can pass the configuration object as below:

```
"scripts": [
  { 
    "input": "./worker.js", 
    "inject": false, 
    "bundleName": "worker" 
  }
]
```

In the above case, you can have more control over the name of the bundled js file.
Since you know the name of the bundle, you can directly specify it in your html as

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="worker.js">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no ```worker.js``` in my codebase. It is automatically bundled from the Angular CLI (webpack) from ```worker.ts```

Answer (score 0):

What I've had to resort to is to turn off the output hashing of filenames. In the `angular.json` file:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    //..
    "outputHashing": "none",
    //...
  }
}
```

This way you get plain file names. So the generated worker file will be `worker.js`.